# how to fix the problem on building model using (self)

Tags: python, keras

```
def build_model(self):
        """Build a critic (value) network that maps (state, action) pairs -> Q-values."""
        # Define input layers
        states = layers.Input(shape=(self.state_size,), name='states')
        actions = layers.Input(shape=(self.action_size,), name='actions')

        # Add hidden layer(s) for state pathway
        net_states = layers.Dense(units=32, activation='relu')(states)
        net_states = layers.Dense(units=64, activation='relu')(net_states)

        # Add hidden layer(s) for action pathway
        net_actions = layers.Dense(units=32, activation='relu')(actions)
        net_actions = layers.Dense(units=64, activation='relu')(net_actions)

        # Try different layer sizes, activations, add batch normalization, regularizers, etc.

        # Combine state and action pathways
        net = layers.Add()([net_states, net_actions])
        net = layers.Activation('relu')(net)

        # Add more layers to the combined network if needed

        # Add final output layer to prduce action values (Q values)
        Q_values = layers.Dense(units=1, name='q_values')(net)

        # Create Keras model
        self.model = models.Model(inputs=[states, actions], outputs=Q_values)

        # Define optimizer and compile model for training with built-in loss function
        optimizer = optimizers.Adam()
        self.model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='mse')

        # Compute action gradients (derivative of Q values w.r.t. to actions)
        action_gradients = K.gradients(Q_values, actions)

        # Define an additional function to fetch action gradients (to be used by actor model)
        self.get_action_gradients = K.function(
            inputs=[*self.model.input, K.learning_phase()],
            outputs=action_gradients)
```

THIS IS THE ERROR --->

```
TypeError: Cannot convert a symbolic Keras input/output to a numpy array. This error may indicate that you're trying to pass a symbolic value to a NumPy call, which is not supported. Or, you may be trying to pass Keras symbolic inputs/outputs to a TF API that does not register dispatching, preventing Keras from automatically converting the API call to a lambda layer in the Functional Model.
```

Comment: Please also show the traceback for the error. We need to know which call yields it.

Comment: the code is the class DDPG of agent

Comment: here it is the site web : https://github.com/pfoy/Quadcopter-Deep-Reinforcement-Learning/blob/master/Quadcopter_Project.ipynb